# Guaranteed HTML information if single-page web application (SPA) is not accessed at the root

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Say I have a completely single-page-application that serves HTML but only at the root:

So with a node.js Express server, that might look like:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res,next){

   res.render('index',{});

});
```

my question is, if an end-user has a completely clean cache and he hits the root of the app, the server will send the html file (titled 'index.html') and all is well. However, if the user has a completely clean cache and hits anything but the root route, how does the user's web browser know what the DOM should look like? In other words, as a single-page-app designer, how do I ensure that this index html page represents the layout of the app throughout it's lifecycle on the front-end from beginning to end?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit based on some comments**

The concept you're referring to is called **UI routing**, which is a farily common paradigm within single page applications. (Google Backbone UI router, AngularJS UI router, etc. You'll see plenty of pre-built examples, which will give you an idea of how to implement your own.)

Conceptually, you'd use a router on the front-end that, for every route, it simply sends a GET request for `index.html` (the first time you access the page). Then, the router parses the route (for example, `/some-view`), and based on that route, it shows or hides a specific portion of the `index.html` page. It's not a trivial thing, that's why people have built frameworks for it, but you could definitely implement it yourself.

In other words, whenever the user accesses the route `www.yourwebsite.com/some-view`, it never sends a GET request for any other file... no matter what, you always send a GET request for the root `/` (but only the first time the page is loaded. If the user goes to `/some-view` from the get-go, `index.html` is still loaded, but the router on the front-end parses that route, and the logic just displays or hides a portion of the page.)

**Further details**

You have a couple options:

1. You need to create routes on the back-end for all possible routes (which wouldn't be a single page app)
2. You need to handle UI routing on the front-end (for example, in AngularJS, you can use `ngRoute`, which just shows a different *view* of the `index.html` page whenever the route changes, but it **never sends a request to the server**.)

In that case, you'd actually want to do something like this on the back-end:

```
app.get('*',function(req,res,next){

   res.render('index',{});

});
```

Because a user could enter in to your application at whatever UI route they want, but it would still need to load the `index.html` page every time (just with a different view on the front-end).

Of course, you'll need different routes to serve static content, etc., but that's just an example.

*Side note*: If using `ngRoute`, I don't think you'd need to make a catch-all route with the `*`. I guess we'll caveat all this with: "it depends on the routing framework you're using".

Comment: I think you understand my question. I definitely don't want to serve HTML with every request. I want to send the HTML just once for every user session. I just want to know for sure how I guarantee that the user has the index.html information, even if he hits the app for the first time at a route other than the index ('/') route. I think this is a legit question and bet most people have no idea how to answer it. My guess is that most of the time (>99.5%) users hit the canonical route first so that HTML file gets cached and there are no problems.

Comment: but for a completely single-page app, I believe that I need to make sure the user has the index.html information first before anything else happens, and I might need to do that on the front-end before every request. It could be a simple check to see if that file is in the cache. IDK.

Comment: @AlexMills, That's exactly what my answer detailed. Did you look up `ngRoute`? I understand your question, it's a pretty common one. I'd suggest looking up how AngularJS deals with Ui routing to give yourself an idea of one possible method.

Comment: I am working with Backbone right now, not Angular, I haven't used Angular before and the project I am working on won't be using it. I'd rather know how to solve this problem conceptually than with a framework anyway

Comment: @AlexMills, Conceptually, you'd use a router on the front-end that, for every route, it simply sends a `GET` request for `index.html`. Then, the router parses the route (for example, `/some-view`), and based on that route, it shows or hides a specific portion of the `index.html` page. It's not a trivial thing, that's why people have built frameworks for it, but you could definitely implement it yourself.

Comment: thanks, that makes some sense, but like I said I still don't want to request/send the html for every front-end/back-end route. I think the solution is simpler. Maybe you could answer this question - my web app just uses hashes on the front-end like so -  /#home, /#jam, /#rock, so it could be that all those routes, if typed straight into the browser, would direct to the canonical route anyway?

Comment: For any other route with a hash as first character, say the user requests '/home' instead of '/#home'.....on the back-end it would just redirect the user to '/' and serve up index.html. Maybe you can tell me if '/' + '#' always points to the '/' route on the back-end. I am pretty new to this web development thing.

Comment: @AlexMills, The solution I provided you **does not** send a request every time. A UI router on the front-end **does not** send any request *except for the very first time a person accesses the page*. UI routers specifically *prevent you from sending a request to the server when changing view routes*.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, what did you mean by this "Conceptually, you'd use a router on the front-end that, for every route, it simply sends a GET request for index.html. "

Comment: @AlexMills, "for every route, it simply sends a GET request for index.html." meaning, the first time the page is accessed, it sends the GET request to index.html. I would seriously suggest looking up some pre-built frameworks for this (Google Backbone UI router, since you say you are using Backbone for this app.)

Comment: hey Josh can you speak this this?

http://artsy.github.io/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/

Comment: I can say two things (1) if you send a request to the server for www.your-app.com/#home, it will actually be routed to the canonical route / not to /#home. I guess that's the purpose of the # character. This is something I didn't really know for sure before. (2) The way my backbone app is now, the backbone app never sends a GET request for html. The user does a GET request when the user first hits the site with the browser. Upon that request, the backbone app gets loaded from a single entry point. It will load the same way every time, but it will never subsequently request HTML after 1st load

Comment: But like I said, the Backbone app never sends a request for HTML - this is different than your suggestion. Furthermore, the only way the front-end knows that backbone exists is of course in one script tag in the index.html file.

Comment: @AlexMills, I haven't personally used the stuff in the link you provided, but it looks like it makes sense. And yeah, totally makes sense what you're saying about initial load of the app, and how the front-end doesn't know that backbone exists until the `index.html` loads. Good points all around.

Comment: I think I was missing the concept of the # and #! as being key for SPAs...they seems to act like comments in the url line for the server but not for the front-end, if you catch my drift, thanks for your help

Comment: @AlexMills, yeah I guess they sort of act like comments; I think the hash bangs basically are a way to use the History API (not sure about that, I'd have to read more in depth), but I think the important part is that hash bangs are an easy way to prevent any request from being sent to the server (for example, whenever you put `#some-div` in a `href`, it'll scroll to that `div`, vs sending a request to the server. Different concept than a UI router, but the behavior is the same in that no request is sent.)